# Add a progress bar in pytube

Tags: python, pytube

I would like to know how can i add a progress bar to this program.

```
from pytube import YouTube

link = input("Paste the link: ")
yt = YouTube(link)

print("Title: ", yt.title)
print("Lengths: ", yt.length)

print(yt.streams.filter(progressive=True))

linkNew = input("Please enter an itag: ")

ys = yt.streams.get_by_itag(linkNew)

ys.download()
ys.download('/home/senjufy/Desktop/')

print("Download Complete!")
```

This is the code.

Comment: What output you are getting in console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's a hack that might stop working any time, but you can put the following callback to get the progress.

```
ys.old_on_progress = ys.on_progress


def progress(chunk, fh, bytes_remaining):
    ys.old_on_progress(chunk, fh, bytes_remaining)
    print(bytes_remaining)


ys.on_progress = progress
```

Second way is to make a usage of the `Borg pattern` on the pytube code and use a monostate class to check the progress:

```
ys._monostate.on_progress = lambda stream, chunk, bytes_remaining: print(bytes_remaining)
```

Then using the progress you might use e.g. `tqdm` to set the progress bar.

Comment: Thanks for replying i will check it out.